# How to type the __new__ method in a Python metaclass so that mypy is happy

Tags: python, metaclass, typing

I am trying to type the `__new__` method in a metaclass in Python so that it pleases mypy. The code would be something like this (taken from [pep-3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/#example) - "Metaclasses in Python 3000" and stripped down a bit):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Type


# The metaclass
class MetaClass(type):

    # The metaclass invocation
    def __new__(cls: Type[type], name: str, bases: tuple, classdict: dict) -> type:
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)
        print('in __new__')
        return result


class MyClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass
```

With this, mypy complains, `Incompatible return type for "__new__" (returns "type", but must return a subtype of "MetaClass")`, pointing at the line `def __new__`.

I have also tried with:

```py
def __new__(cls: Type[MetaClass], name: str, bases: tuple, classdict: dict) -> MetaClass:
```

Then mypy complains (about the `return result` line): `Incompatible return value type (got "type", expected "MetaClass")`.

I have also tried with a type var (`TSubMetaclass = TypeVar('TSubMetaclass', bound='MetaClass')`) and the result is the same as using `MetaClass`.

Using `super().__new__` instead of `type.__new__` gave similar results.

What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the return type is `MetaClass`, not `type`. Second, you need to explicitly cast the return value, since `type.__new__` doesn't know it is returning an instance of `MetaClass`. (Its specific return type is determined by its first argument, which isn't known statically.)

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Type, cast


# The metaclass
class MetaClass(type):

    # The metaclass invocation
    def __new__(cls: Type[type], name: str, bases: tuple, classdict: dict) -> MetaClass:
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)
        print('in __new__')
        return cast(MetaClass, result)


class MyClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass
```

---

To use `super`, you need to adjust the static type of the `cls` parameter.

```
class MetaClass(type):

    # The metaclass invocation
    def __new__(cls: Type[MetaClass], name: str, bases: tuple, classdict: dict) -> MetaClass:
        result = super().__new__(name, bases, classdict)
        print('in __new__')
        return cast(MetaClass, result)
```

Comment: That seems like a hack - for example, that signature would prevent you from using `super()`, since the 2nd arg would not be an instance of the 1st. Well, to be honest, `cast` seems generally wrong in Python typing, like a lie. It seems to me that if we start with something like `def __new__(cls: Type[MetaClass [...]`, then `type.__new__(cls [...]` should understand that it is returning an instance of `MetaClass`. So I'll wait to see if there is some solution w/o using `cast` before accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're not wrong. I did notice the issue with `super`, which is why I didn't include it in the answer.

Comment: The problem with `super` can be resolved by changing the annotation of `cls` to `Type[MetaClass]`, but I think that has its own issues if you have a metaclass hierarchy. (I shudder at the thought of anything that complex, though.)

Comment: Mmm yes, if we change the `cls` annotation to `Type[MetaClass]` *and* we cast the result, we can use `super()` and it pleases mypy... I really wish there was a solution w/o casting, but for now I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: I'd like to see the answer patched to include the proper `super()` call.